# How to know which headers should be added in a post request

Tags: http, header, request, fiddler

I know there are a lot of questions regarding how to make a Post request in whichever programming language. This is not the case. I just want the theory in this matter.

Let's say I want to perform a login to a website in order to be able to enter in a "private zone".

Which would be the steps i should take? Which tools could I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to simply use Fiddler to look at the request sent by an existing client (e.g. a browser) and then make your code match that.

Many servers require a `POST` request to have `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, `User-Agent`, and `Cookie` headers, but every server may make its own demands.